# Passing variables from activity to class in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, class, variables, android-activity

Looking through similar questions, I have not yet been able to grasp how to transfer variables from an activity to a class in Java. I have been able to transfer the variable another activity to this activity. I now want to pass it on again to the class.

articleID is the variable which I want to set the data to.

**Code in Activity (In onCreate)**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    getarticle mc = new getArticle();
    mc.articleID = extras.getInt("IDPasser");
    Log.e("Info3", mc.articleID.toString());
}
```

I have set the variable in the class.

```
public Integer articleID;
```

Comment: Is that field in the same class as the onCreate method? If so, you can just do `ArticleID = mc.ArticleID;` (note: In Java, variables normally start with a lower case letter). If not, you need to tell us what class you are trying to pass the variable to, and what its relationship is to your Activity.

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer variables from an activity to a class in Java?" An Activity *is* a class. Are you referring to a second Activity or some other GUI-less class that might contain your business logic?

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the class you want to pass data to and initialize the variable in it.

for eg:

```
yourClass urClass = new yourClass();
urClass.ArticleID = ArticleID;
```

Comment: Should be `YourClass` (naming conventions!!).

Comment: Should this be in the receiving class or the Activity class?

Comment: It should be in activity class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best way to "pass a variable to a class" is through a setter like this

```
public void setArticleID(Integer id){
    this.ArticleID = id;
}
```

and make ArticleID private.

and then to access the variables value, use a getter:

```
public Integer getArticleID(){
    return ArticleID;
}
```

Also, don't think of it as passing a variable to a class. An activity is also a class. what you are doing is creating an instance of a class, and then setting the value of its `ArticleID` Variable.